# Why are seemingly on-topic question marked off-topic?

Tags: discussion

I am wondering why one of my question [Bevel operation results in different result in similar mesh](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/226828/bevel-operation-results-in-different-result-in-similar-mesh) was marked off-topic.

As I understand it falls under the topics listed here: [What topics can I ask about here?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)

- Modeling workflows and their related challenges in Blender.

I have not been able to recover the exact blender file that caused the bug, but that would make it an incomplete question - not off-topic.

Comment: Hello and welcome. Off topic message often is shown when different or conflicting reasons for closure are chosen by different users. I chose to close as "*needs details or clarity*" since you mentioned you'd provide a file but haven't done so yet. In this case this doesn't seem to be answerable without one, so if you can provide a working example feel free to edit, so we can reopen

Comment: That makes sense. Thanks for the clarification.

Comment: @DuarteFarrajotaRamos appears to take the option of first vote to close.  Noticed this on a dupe, with  4 or 5 votes for dupe, closed for different reason.

Comment: I think I have an answer to the question if we want to reopen